# Fan max power consumption on MS-7395

Tags: motherboard, cooling, fan

I'm wondering where I can find detailed specification of a MSI MS-7395 motherboard. What bothers me is if I can use 12V 2.6W sys fan on that board. I really don't want to screw the board. Previously, there was 2.2W used. Thanks a lot for help.

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/293499/Msi-Ms-7395.html?page=17

Comment: Is your PC over heating because if it is not there is no real reason to upgrade it unless you are thinking of over-clocking or buying a faster component.

Comment: The reason for change is that original fans are too much noisy now. And I've got these 2.6 available.